# Warning message when using closness() in igraph

Tags: r, graph, igraph

I am looking to calcuate the closeness centrality measure of a  graph of USairports for a set of vertices: ATL, JFK, ORD, LAS

The code I have is as follows:

```
closeness(USairports,vids=c("ATL","JFK","ORD","LAS"),mode="all")
```

This gives me the warning message

> "In closeness(USairports, vids = c("ATL", "JFK", "ORD", "LAS"), mode =
>   "all") :   At centrality.c:2784 :closeness centrality is not
>   well-defined for disconnected graphs"

What does this warning essentially mean?

Answer (score 4):

The warning message tells you directly. "closeness centrality is not well-defined for disconnected graphs".  The help page on `closeness` says:

> The closeness centrality of a vertex is defined by the inverse of the average length of the shortest paths to/from all the other vertices in the graph:

But what if there are two vertices that have *no* path between them? How would you compute this? There is no clear answer to this and that is why closeness is not well defined in this case. How is it possible that two nodes might have no path between them? If the graph is disconnected, i.e. has more than one connected component. Let me illustrate with a very simple graph.

```
library(igraph)
g = make_ring(3) + make_ring(4)
plot(g)
```

[image: Graph with two components]

This graph has two disconnected components. For example, there is no path between nodes 3 and 4. Thus, when we run closeness we get the same warning.

```
closeness(g)
[1] 0.03333333 0.03333333 0.03333333 0.04000000 0.04000000 0.04000000 0.04000000
Warning message:
In closeness(g) :
  At centrality.c:2784 :closeness centrality is not well-defined for disconnected graphs
```

You can easily test for this by checking the number of connected components.

```
ConComp = components(g)
ConComp$no
[1] 2
```

If the number of components is greater than one, you will get this warning message.

I assume that you are using the `USairports` data from the `igraphdata` package. Since that is a directed graph, you will need to specify strong components.

```
library(igraphdata)
data(USairports)
USA_CC = components(USairports, mode="strong")
USA_CC$no
[1] 30
USA_CC$csize
 [1]  1   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  1  2  1  1  2  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
[24]  1 723  1  1  1  1  1
```

Most airports are in one big component, but there are several that are in small components. It might make sense in this case to restrict your attention to the 723 airports that all connect with each other.

```
BigComp = which.max(USA_CC$csize)
Main_USairports = induced_subgraph(USairports, 
    which(USA_CC$membership == BigComp))
closeness(Main_USairports)
```

<No warning message>